# Сдвигание блока при fixed

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Дело такое, есть блок с

> position:fixed

и под ним есть другой

> div

вот как сделать есть чтобы когда блок с

> position:fixed

виден , нижний спускался на высоту этого блока ?

Вот то что я пытался сделать

```
$(".helpMenuWhite").click(function(){
                if($(".helpMenuWhite").css("position") == "fixed")
                {
                    $(".test").css("margin-top","100px");
                }else{
                    $(".test").css("display","none");
                }
            });
```

Comment: А что влияет на видимость блока с фикс. позиционированием? Он показывается-скрывается скриптом?

Comment: @gold он под ним останется, если блок "с" с css свойством position: fixed и margin-top: 0; Если же у блока "с" position != fixed, то второй блок будет спрятан.

Comment: Может, речь идёт про динамический layout: когда прокручивается страница, и под фикс. блоком оказывается другой, тот сдвигался бы ниже, чтобы фикс. верхний его не перекрывал?

Comment: @gold если у вас jQuery, то так: .css("margin-top",value+100); Если же нет, то вам сначала результат нужно привести к числовому виду, т.к. высота обычно выглядит так: "100px", с помощью функции обрезается эти "px", т.е.: parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(block_c, null).height) + 100 + px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var block_c = ...
var block_d = ...

if(block_c.style.display != 'none') {
    block_d.style.top = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(block_c, null).top) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(block_c, null).height) + 'px';
}
```

У блока `d` также нужно дописать: `position (relative, absolute, fixed)`

Comment: @gold http://jsfiddle.net/8syNN/

Comment: @gold

     block_d.style.marginTop = window.getComputedStyle(block_c, null).height;

Comment: @lampa чет не то, либо я объясняю криво

Comment: @gold нарисуйте, что "есть" и что "хотите получить".

Comment: @lampa Смотрите
1) Если блок `<div class="position:fixed;height:30px;">` фиксирован, то нижестоящему блоку добавляется `margin-top:30px`,
2) Если нет , то этот блок получает `display:none`

Comment: ну так добавьте условие else, где block_d.style.display = 'none'; А условие замените на block_c.style.position == 'fixed'

Comment: @lampa так он под ним же и останется?

Comment: @lampa Все разобрался, не внимательность моя подвела ) Спасибо за помощь, а как еще чуть отступа добавить ?